# Python: problemas com calculadora(?)

Tags: python

Sou nova na área, estou com dificuldade com um exercício.

O enunciado:

> Faça um programa modularizado em Python com as seguintes funções:
>
> - atualiza_preco(valor): a função deve receber como parâmetro o valor de um produto, calcular e retornar este valor com aumento de 10%
> - taxa(valor): a função calcula e retorna o valor da taxa de 2.5% sobre o valor do produto atualizado (após a chamada da função
>   atualiza_preco).
> - main(): terá o programa principal que deve,
>   nesta ordem, fazer a entrada via teclado (digitada pelo usuário) do
>   valor do produto, depois chamar as funções atualiza_preco e taxa e
>   apresentar os valores calculados do valor atualizado com duas casas
>   decimais e do valor da taxa também com duas casas decimais.
>   Ao final, chame a função main() para que o programa seja executado.

Tentei fazer um código, mas o cálculo não funciona.

```
def atualiza_preco(valor):
  return valor*0.1

def taxa(valor):
  return valor*0.0025


def main():

  valor= float (input())
  print (valor*0.1)
  
  if valor > 0:  
    result= valor*0.0025
    print(f'{result:.2f}')

main ()
```

Comment: Olhando por cima, parece que o erro é só na função `atualiza_preco`, o return deveria ser `return valor+(valor*0.1)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Segue o código comentado, espero que ajude a entender

```
# Função de atualizar em 10% o preço
def atualiza_preco(valor):
    valor = valor * 1.1
    return valor

# Função para calcular uma taxa de 2,5%
def taxa(valor):
    taxa = valor * 0.025
    return taxa


# Função principal
def main():

    #input para o usuário digitar um valor
    entrada = float(input('Entrar o valor do produto: '))

    # Variavel que chama a função atualiza_preco com o valor digitado pelo usuário
    valor_atualizado = atualiza_preco(entrada)
    # variavel que chama a função taxa, com o retorno do valor atualizado
    valor_taxa = taxa(valor_atualizado)

    # Print formatado com f'string 
        # :.2f faz com que retorne com 2 digitos após a virgula
    print(f'O valor atualizado é: {valor_atualizado:.2f}')
    print(f'O valor da taxa é: {valor_taxa:.2f}')

#chamar a função main
main()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def atualizar_preco(valor):
    porcentagem = valor + (valor * 10/100)
    print( '{:.2f}' .format (porcentagem));


def taxa(valor):
    porcentagem = (valor + (valor * 10/100)) * 2.5/100
    print( '{:.2f}' .format (porcentagem))


def main():

    valor = float(input());

    atualizar_preco(valor)
    taxa(valor)
main()
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).